WaterLevel Indicator Flutter Custom Paint
How Can I create this shape using custom paint in Flutter, Here the blue water wave will show the water level in the tank. Two Examples are shown here for 44% and 56%. It will come through zero to exact value through a Tween Animation. I have tried it but can't be satisfied through it as I've a little bit experience in custom paint. Here is the what I have done.

class FuelTankCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  FuelTankCustomPainter(this.context, this.value);

  final BuildContext context;
  final double value;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // assuming the original design width is 180 (width scale)
    double ws = size.width / 180;
    // assuming the original design height is 216 (height scale)
    double hs = size.height / 216;

    Path bgPath = Path();
    bgPath.moveTo(82.9262 * ws, 16.5416 * hs);
    bgPath.cubicTo(
      84.9174 * ws,
      14.8986 * hs,
      87.4185 * ws,
      14 * hs,
      90 * ws,
      14 * hs,
    );
    bgPath.cubicTo(
      92.5816 * ws,
      14 * hs,
      95.0826 * ws,
      14.8986 * hs,
      97.0738 * ws,
      16.5416 * hs,
    );
    bgPath.cubicTo(
      110.61 * ws,
      27.7963 * hs,
      123.011 * ws,
      40.3491 * hs,
      134.101 * ws,
      54.0205 * hs,
    );
    bgPath.cubicTo(
      149.548 * ws,
      73.2261 * hs,
      165.353 * ws,
      99.2889 * hs,
      165.353 * ws,
      126.548 * hs,
    );
    bgPath.cubicTo(
      165.353 * ws,
      146.533 * hs,
      157.414 * ws,
      165.699 * hs,
      143.283 * ws,
      179.831 * hs,
    );
    bgPath.cubicTo(
      129.151 * ws,
      193.962 * hs,
      109.985 * ws,
      201.901 * hs,
      90 * ws,
      201.901 * hs,
    );
    bgPath.cubicTo(
      70.0151 * ws,
      201.901 * hs,
      50.8487 * ws,
      193.962 * hs,
      36.7172 * ws,
      179.831 * hs,
    );
    bgPath.cubicTo(
      22.5857 * ws,
      165.699 * hs,
      14.6467 * ws,
      146.533 * hs,
      14.6467 * ws,
      126.548 * hs,
    );
    bgPath.cubicTo(
      14.6467 * ws,
      99.2889 * hs,
      30.4521 * ws,
      73.2261 * hs,
      45.8995 * ws,
      54.011 * hs,
    );
    bgPath.cubicTo(
      56.9867 * ws,
      40.3435 * hs,
      69.3943 * ws,
      27.7939 * hs,
      82.9262 * ws,
      16.5416 * hs,
    );
    bgPath.close();

    Paint bgFill = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    bgFill.color = context.theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor;
    canvas.drawPath(bgPath, bgFill);

    // Calculate the fuel level height
    double fuelLevelHeight = 209 - (209 * value);

    Path behindDrop = Path();
    behindDrop.moveTo(170.377 * ws, fuelLevelHeight * hs);
    behindDrop.cubicTo(
      170.377 * ws,
      173.014 * hs,
      134.391 * ws,
      209 * hs,
      90 * ws,
      209 * hs,
    );
    behindDrop.cubicTo(
      45.6089 * ws,
      209 * hs,
      9.62317 * ws,
      173.014 * hs,
      9.62317 * ws,
      fuelLevelHeight * hs,
    );
    behindDrop.cubicTo(
      9.62317 * ws,
      fuelLevelHeight * hs,
      52.4908 * ws,
      148.273 * hs,
      90 * ws,
      fuelLevelHeight * hs,
    );
    behindDrop.cubicTo(
      132.868 * ws,
      108.084 * hs,
      170.377 * ws,
      fuelLevelHeight * hs,
      170.377 * ws,
      fuelLevelHeight * hs,
    );
    behindDrop.close();

    Paint behindDropFill = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    behindDropFill.color = const Color(0xff0062E5).withOpacity(1.0);
    canvas.drawPath(behindDrop, behindDropFill);

    Path upperDrop = Path();
    upperDrop.moveTo(9.62317 * ws, fuelLevelHeight * hs);
    upperDrop.cubicTo(
      9.62317 * ws,
      173.014 * hs,
      45.609 * ws,
      209 * hs,
      90 * ws,
      209 * hs,
    );
    upperDrop.cubicTo(
      134.391 * ws,
      209 * hs,
      170.377 * ws,
      173.014 * hs,
      170.377 * ws,
      fuelLevelHeight * hs,
    );
    upperDrop.cubicTo(
      170.377 * ws,
      fuelLevelHeight * hs,
      124.83 * ws,
      148.271 * hs,
      90 * ws,
      fuelLevelHeight * hs,
    );
    upperDrop.cubicTo(
      53.5869 * ws,
      108.084 * hs,
      9.62317 * ws,
      fuelLevelHeight * hs,
      9.62317 * ws,
      fuelLevelHeight * hs,
    );
    upperDrop.close();

    Paint upperDropFill = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    upperDropFill.color = const Color(0xff2F88FF).withOpacity(1.0);
    canvas.drawPath(upperDrop, upperDropFill);

    Path borderPath = Path();
    borderPath.moveTo(73.9955 * ws, 5.75999 * hs);
    borderPath.lineTo(74.0161 * ws, 5.74307 * hs);
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      78.5154 * ws,
      2.03053 * hs,
      84.1668 * ws,
      0,
      90 * ws,
      0,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      95.8333 * ws,
      0,
      101.485 * ws,
      2.03053 * hs,
      105.984 * ws,
      5.74307 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.lineTo(106.004 * ws, 5.75986 * hs);
    borderPath.lineTo(106.025 * ws, 5.77673 * hs);
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      120.263 * ws,
      17.6156 * hs,
      133.308 * ws,
      30.82 * hs,
      144.973 * ws,
      45.201 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.lineTo(144.992 * ws, 45.2235 * hs);
    borderPath.lineTo(145.01 * ws, 45.2461 * hs);
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      160.937 * ws,
      65.0484 * hs,
      179.353 * ws,
      94.3099 * hs,
      179.353 * ws,
      126.548 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      179.353 * ws,
      150.246 * hs,
      169.939 * ws,
      172.973 * hs,
      153.182 * ws,
      189.73 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      136.425 * ws,
      206.487 * hs,
      113.698 * ws,
      215.901 * hs,
      90 * ws,
      215.901 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      66.302 * ws,
      215.901 * hs,
      43.5747 * ws,
      206.487 * hs,
      26.8177 * ws,
      189.73 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      10.0607 * ws,
      172.973 * hs,
      0.646729 * ws,
      150.246 * hs,
      0.646729 * ws,
      126.548 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      0.646729 * ws,
      94.3101 * hs,
      19.0631 * ws,
      65.0486 * hs,
      34.9882 * ws,
      45.2392 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.lineTo(35.0076 * ws, 45.2152 * hs);
    borderPath.lineTo(35.027 * ws, 45.1912 * hs);
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      46.6919 * ws,
      30.8115 * hs,
      59.7435 * ws,
      17.611 * hs,
      73.9751 * ws,
      5.777 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.lineTo(73.9955 * ws, 5.75999 * hs);
    borderPath.close();
    borderPath.moveTo(97.0738 * ws, 16.5416 * hs);
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      95.0826 * ws,
      14.8986 * hs,
      92.5816 * ws,
      14 * hs,
      90 * ws,
      14 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      87.4185 * ws,
      14 * hs,
      84.9174 * ws,
      14.8986 * hs,
      82.9262 * ws,
      16.5416 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      69.3943 * ws,
      27.7939 * hs,
      56.9867 * ws,
      40.3435 * hs,
      45.8995 * ws,
      54.011 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      30.4521 * ws,
      73.2261 * hs,
      14.6467 * ws,
      99.2889 * hs,
      14.6467 * ws,
      126.548 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      14.6467 * ws,
      146.533 * hs,
      22.5857 * ws,
      165.699 * hs,
      36.7172 * ws,
      179.831 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      50.8487 * ws,
      193.962 * hs,
      70.0151 * ws,
      201.901 * hs,
      90 * ws,
      201.901 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      109.985 * ws,
      201.901 * hs,
      129.151 * ws,
      193.962 * hs,
      143.283 * ws,
      179.831 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      157.414 * ws,
      165.699 * hs,
      165.353 * ws,
      146.533 * hs,
      165.353 * ws,
      126.548 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      165.353 * ws,
      99.2889 * hs,
      149.548 * ws,
      73.2261 * hs,
      134.101 * ws,
      54.0205 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.cubicTo(
      123.011 * ws,
      40.3491 * hs,
      110.61 * ws,
      27.7963 * hs,
      97.0738 * ws,
      16.5416 * hs,
    );
    borderPath.close();

    Paint borderFill = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    borderFill.color = context.theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor;
    canvas.drawShadow(
      borderPath,
      context.theme.dividerColor.withOpacity(0.3),
      15.0,
      true,
    );
    canvas.drawPath(borderPath, borderFill);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}





checkout these packages https://pub.dev/packages/wave https://pub.dev/packages/water_bottle

Thank you for your suggestion. those packages are good but backdated and don't match with my design.

you can look into the design they are in pure dart and you can fintune it according to your design.
